# when use sp_send_dbmail , got error : mail server failure , The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found)

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

when i use this code try to  send a email from sql server

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @recipients='yang.liu@hotmail.com',
        @body= 'abc', 
        @subject = 'new request',
        @profile_name ='thisProfile'
```

sql server management  show me : Mail queued.

but actually, this email is not been send , when i check log to see the reason :

```
SELECT TOP 100 [log_id]
      ,[event_type]
      ,[log_date]
      ,[description]
      ,[process_id]
      ,[mailitem_id]
      ,[account_id]
      ,[last_mod_date]
      ,[last_mod_user]
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysmail_event_log]

  order by [log_id] desc
```

the log show me :

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2014-07-10T10:34:17). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found).
```

could anyone tell me what the reason , thanks

Comment: How is you account configured? Has you checked that there is connectivity from your server to the mail server? Does the databse user have permissions to use the network?

Comment: my email account is nothing wrong , but i do not know how to exam if database user have permission to use network, could you tell me how to check it

Comment: You should try this troubleshooting procedures: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188663(v=sql.105).aspx